# Non-breaking hyphen longer than regular

Tags: flash, unicode, tlf, word-processor

I'm working on an application that uses Adobe's [Text Layout Framework](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/tlf/demo/) to handle word processing. I've run into an issue where inserting a non-breaking hyphen (U+2011) is rendered about twice as long as a regular ascii-hyphen (U+2010).

MS Word (as well as other similar applications) uses the same size of hyphen for each instance, whether or not it is non-breaking.

`The following is in Times New Roman and zoomed to 500%:`

[image: Inconsistent Hyphenation]

In the TLF markup, both hyphens seem to be the same width. I'm pretty confused as to how exactly to troubleshoot this particular annoyance.

```
<p>
  <span>- ascii hyphen</span>
<p>
<p>
  <span>— em dash</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>– en dash</span>
</p>
<p>
  <span>‑ non-breaking hyphen</span>
</p>
```

Is this just a font bug? Arial seems to have the same problem, so I'm hesitant to blame font support. Are there any TLF experts out there who have dealt with an issue like this before?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this just a font bug?

Yes.

Neither Times New Roman nor Arial [support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2011/fontsupport.htm) U+2011 Non-Breaking Hyphen. (Arial Unicode does, but that's an unfortunate typeface.) It'll fall back to whatever other font it can find which has that character, which means you get an inconsistent mix of styles.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me to the root of the problem. Do you have any suggestions as to how to go about solving it? I'd like to have the ascii-hyphen and non-breaking hyphen look the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TLF and don't know if there's any way to mess with the rendering/wrapping (ie to treat normal hyphen as non-breaking). Do you have any control over the fonts in use? If you defaulted to Palatino the problem might be hidden :-)

Comment: I don't think defaulting to a different font is in the cards for this particular project. I think I'll have to do a bit of digging into TLF to see if it is possible. I'm also not all that familiar with the framework either :p thanks for your help!